# Figuring out C++ set

Tags: c++, syntax, set

Could someone give me some guidance or direct me to a good tutorial on C++ `set` object?

I have a piece of simple code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char set[8];
    int set[9];
    return 0;
}
```

But the `set` in this code is apparently different than the `set` in this reference? :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/

If I try to compile this code I get the following error:

[image]

What is troubling me is that when defining the `set` in the code there is no variable / identifier for the `set` defined? Or is this a default constructor or something. Why do I get the error I get? Can't you create two objects from `set`? Why? Sorry if my question is newbie, but I don't seem to find any examples of this...so I don't understand how to work with `set`...

thnx for any help =)

Comment: Did you look at the example on the `set` documentation page *you* mentioned?

Comment: @Andrei yes I did =) But it seemed something completely different :O ?...initialization and everything...but it is the same object?

Comment: I just clicked the link referred by you... and answer was there :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi you can thank us by accepting an answere

Comment: I will @Paranaix just 4 more minutes ;) Can't yet, SO won't let me :)

Comment: @Paranaix: Chill out he only asked 19 mins ago!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're naming an array of char's as "set".
Subsequently you are naming an array of int's as "set".

What you really want to do is as follows:

```
std::set<char> my_chars;
std::set<int>  my_ints;
```

The "<>" angle brackets pass a type to the std::set class template when you instantiate it.

Comment: :std:: is not required in this case. Since using directive used here.

Comment: yup. true.. just typed it in out of habit.

Comment: Is that what he wants?  Or is he confusing `std::set` with the mathematical concept of a set?  (His use of `&` above seems to suggest that he's thinking of a set that you can and and or.  But who knows.)  And while I'm at it: you could mention name hiding in your answer, since that's what happens when he defines a variable named `set`.

Comment: @JamesKanze not if he uses namespaces properly like it was done in the answere

Comment: `std::set` is not a class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you mean I should call it a "templated class" or is there something deeper that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, guys =) Don't worry about the variables a, b and c :) I'm just learning the language and playing around =) I'm just interested on the set =)

Comment: @Jmc: It is a "class template". Exactly that. It is not a class in the slightest, "templated" or otherwise; it is a template. When you instantiate the template, you get a class. Nothing deeper. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the line

```
char set[8];
```

you define a variable with **name** "set" and **type** `char[8]`.

In the line

```
int set[9];
```

you define another variable with **name** "set" and **type** `int[9]`. (which should cause a compiler error, because you cannot define two things with the same name in the same scope)

The linked reference concerns the **type** `std::set<T>`. You can define a variable of type `std::set<int>` (you have to substitute something for T before you can use the set)
using the syntax

```
std::set<int> my_set;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the same variable `set` with the type `char`, and `set` again but this time with type `int`. This is causing the problem.

Try declaring the following:

```
set<char> setchar;
set<int>  setint;
```

Don't forget to `#include <set>`.

Comment: Can you clean this up a bit?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:Done

Comment: Not really, no >.< For example, there is no such standard header as `"#include<set>".`